# how to reload gird data after add new data in to the store

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have two grids; I call them child and parent grid. When I add a new row(data) into the parent grid, I want to reload the parent grid. I was trying to edit it using the afteredit function in the code. If I uncomment out line number 2 in the alert, that works fine. But  with out the alert, the newly added row is hidden. I don't understand what's going wrong in my code. Please can anyone tell me what to do after I add the new row in to my grid and how to reload the grid immediately?

this my afteredit function

```
   afteredit : function (roweditor, changes, record, rowIndex) 
   { //alert('alert me');
      if (!roweditor.initialized) {
         roweditor.initFields();
      }
      var fields = roweditor.items.items;
      // Disable key fields if its not a new row
      Ext.each(fields, function (field, i) {
         field.setReadOnly(false);
         field.removeClass('x-item-disabled');
      });

        this.grid.getSelectionModel().selectRow(0);
        this.grid.getView().refresh();
   },


xt.ux.grid.woerp = 
{
   configRowEditor: 
   {
      saveText: "Save",
      cancelText: "Cancel",
      commitChangesText: WOERP.constants.gridCommitChanges,
      errorText: 'Errors',
      listeners: 
      {
         beforeedit: WOERP.grid.handler.beforeedit,
         validateedit: WOERP.grid.handler.validateedit,
         canceledit: WOERP.grid.handler.canceledit,
         afteredit: WOERP.grid.handler.afteredit,
         aftershow: WOERP.grid.handler.aftershow,
         move: WOERP.grid.handler.resize,
         hide: function (p) 
         {
            var mainBody = this.grid.getView().mainBody;
            if (typeof mainBody != 'undefined') 
            {
               var lastRow = Ext.fly(this.grid.getView().getRow(this.grid.getStore().getCount() - 1));
               if (lastRow != null) 
               {
                  mainBody.setHeight(lastRow.getBottom() - mainBody.getTop(), 
                  {
                     callback: function () 
                     {
                        mainBody.setHeight('auto');
                     }
                  });
               }
            }
         },
         afterlayout: WOERP.grid.handler.resize
     }
   },
```

Comment: The grid is for displaying data only, it cannot save records. I'm guessing that you use a store associated with the grid. Which methods are you using to save your data?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. how can i reload after add new record in to the store. my store is "parentStroe"

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK `RowEditor` is a plugin for `GridPanel` which changes underlying data which comes from store. Usually updates are also made by store. If you want to know when data is saved, you should attach event handler to store. Example:

```
grid.getStore().on('save', function(){ [...] });
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found solution. When i add reload function in to the afteredit method that will be hide newly added row. So  Grid reload  After commit data in to that data grid store work well for me. Anyway thanks lot all the people who try to help

this my code look like

```
record.commit();
grid.getView().refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there exist a **Save** button after editing grid.
So in the `handler` of **Save** you can catch the event

or using

```
Ext.getCmp('your_saveButtonId').on('click', function(component, e) {
   // Here they will be checking for modified records and sending them to backend to save.
   // So here also you can catch save event
}
```

Comment: yes there is save button and i find afteredit event but i try to reload grid in the afteredit function. but when i reload grid in the afteredit function that hide my newly add item form the grid panel. If i add alert in afteredit function that work ok with alert. i'm very new to extjs

Comment: Duleep don't load grid in after edit. you loose the edited data.
They may be calling server function using ajax or some method.
If ajax then in success block of that ajax you need to reload grid so that the new data will be loaded into grid by making an server call again.

This ajax will be inside that button handler I guess.